# How to simulate/animate a swipe over android View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-canvas, android-recyclerview

I have this items inside my RecyclerView:

[image]

When user swipes in any of the items a background with a Canvas, with a Paint instance (that colors the background pink) and a Bitmap for deleteIcon (trash icon appears) like this:
[image]

A bit more swipe

[image]

This is my code that makes pink colored background and trashicon image appear as user swiped by using `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` and method `onChildDraw()`:

```
public class CartSwipeListener extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback{

     //more code....

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        //If user is Swiping over item
        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            // Get RecyclerView item from the ViewHolder
            View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;

            //The color for the background that appears when swiping
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_A));

            //Make options so Bitmap isn't displayed pixelated
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inScaled = false;

            //create the deleteIcon
            Bitmap deleteIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_trash, options);

            // Draw background rectangle with varying left side, equal to the item's right side plus negative displacement dX
            c.drawRect(
                    (float) itemView.getRight() + dX,    //left: notice we use + dX which is displacement of X by swipe
                    (float) itemView.getTop(),           //top
                    (float) itemView.getRight(),         //right
                    (float) itemView.getBottom(),        //bottom
                    p                                    //paint
            );

            //Draw the deleteIcon
            c.drawBitmap(
                    deleteIcon, //Bitmap to be drawn
                    (float) itemView.getRight()/1.1f, // position of the LEFT side of the bitmap being drawn
                    (float) itemView.getTop() + ((float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop() - deleteIcon.getHeight()) / 2, //The position of the TOP side of the bitmap being drawn
                    null //The paint used to draw the bitmap (may be null)
            );
        }

        //Default onChildDraw implementation
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
```

## My problem:

I need to only animate the first row of RecyclerView like if it was swiped more or less 100px to the left, then pink background shows and trash icon shows and then undo swipe and return to original position. This is to give the user a hint that he/she can swipe to delete.

I have been reading about animation but I have no idea how to draw something that isn't in the itemView all the tutorials I find just manipulate the view (rotation, fadein, etc) without adding a canvas with a bitmap just like I do on swipe.